# synchronization strategy for android async task

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I am trying to implement a simple synchronization strategy in android.

A service instantiates class A and calls it's method `sendToServer()` for every iteration of a loop. This results in multiple Async tasks being started and the service ends immediately. The service may run again anytime and repeat the process.

So, to prevent two Async tasks from taking the same input, i store the Ids in a synchronized list and check the list before i start the async task.

But i am confused which piece of code i need to put in a `synchronized` block? Do i define the entire method `isAlreadyRunning()` as `synchronized`? Or do i not need to define any synchronized block of code at all?

Here is my class :

```
public class A{
    private static List<Integer> idList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());

    private boolean isAlreadyRunning(id){
        //iterate through the list and return true if the id is already present
        ....
        }

    private class sendToServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //send http request 
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            idList.remove(id);
            }
        }

    public void sendToServer(int id) {
        if(isAlreadyRunning(id)){
            // an async task is already running for this id.
            //,so dont start the async task again, just exit
            return; 
        else {
            idList.add(id);
            new sendToServerAsyncTask(id).execute();
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: ASyncTasks should not be recycled, they are fire-and-forget. If you want a queue that is worked off, you should consider a normal thread.

Comment: @NikkyD yes i basically want to move through a cursor and send http requests for every row in the cursor. If i do this in a normal thread, would'nt it block the UI?

Comment: @faizal No, only if you executed your code on the main thread it would block the UI. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Android's documentation

**ASYNC TASK's ORDER OF EXECUTION**

When first introduced, `AsyncTasks` were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with `DONUT`, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with `HONEYCOMB`, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

The instances of `Asynctask` are already placed in a queue maintained by the framework and they are executed sequentially i.e. only after one task finishes the other will start so there is no chance of issue due to parallel execution because it doesn't exist.

So you need not do anything and the framework will take care of it for you.

Comment: So, what, upgrading to a newer version where they revert it again will introduce concurrency errors? Great advice...

Comment: @Ordous See the updated answer. From `HoneyComb` till `KitKat` they are following serial execution and it was changed to this due to bugs introduced due to parallel execution. So i think it will remain the same in the future as well.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior wow that's news to me. The threading rules at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html also says `The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)`.

Comment: Then it'll break if he runs it on a phone running 2.3 or earlier.  Or if he defines it to run on a parallel executor because that's faster than running unrelated tasks sequentially.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior, by "sequentially", do you think that a new async task will start after `doInBackground()` has completed execution and before the `onPostExecute` starts ? This doubt arises because the `onPostExecute` executes on the UI thread, which implies that the background thread is ready for the next async task by the time `doInBackground()` has completed. Basically i am wondering if some kind of synchronization is required in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: @faizal All the `doInBackground()` are executed sequentially. Suppose the first finishes, `onPostExecute()` is called for the first one UI is updated and then second `doInbackground()` starts and so on. Are you sure u wanna update your UI, if not then better to use `Thread` and in case you wanna update UI then change implementation to something that after all background task completes    call your `onPostExecute()` just once.

Comment: I just tested this out. The `doInBackground()` of the successive async task can start before the `onPostExecute()` of the previous async task has started. So the execution of async tasks is not completely sequential. You are right, I probably need to to use `Thread` instead of `AsynTask`.

Comment: Moved from answer to comments. @faizal wrote: Note that only `doInBackground()` is executed sequentially by the framework. So it is possible that `onPostExecute()` of one async task might run in parallel with the `doInBackground()` of the next async task.